# OfficeJS error in debugging mode for Desktop Version only

Tags: office-js

I am getting below error in working code suddenly when trying to run Desktop Version. Same working for online version like running npm run Dev-Server.

Even tried in different port 5003.

```
> Executing task: npm run start:desktop <    
> excel-custom-functions@2.0.0 start:desktop C:\Users\user\Desktop\BatchingReCalculate\Batching
> office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml deskto`enter code here`p
Debugging is being started...
App type: desktop
Enabled debugging for add-in e504fb41-a92a-4526-b101-542f357b7acb. Debug method: 0
Starting the dev server... (webpack-dev-server --mode development --config webpack.config.js)
Unable to start the dev server. Error: The dev server is not running on port 3000.
Sideloading the Office Add-in...
Unable to sideload the Office Add-in. Error: Command failed: office-toolbox sideload -m manifest.xml -a excel
ApplicationInsights:CorrelationIdManager [
  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxx
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1129:14) {
    errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: 'xx.xx.xx.xxx',
    port: xxx
  }
]
```

Comment: Looks like you need to kill the port 3000 before running `npm run Dev-Server`

Comment: To kill the task ` 1.netstat -ano | findstr :3000
2.taskkill /PID 4164 /F` . 1. Get the PID from the 1st command and put it in second command

Comment: No I think.  Since usually I used to the steps you mentioned for the scenario when "port already in use".

Comment: Hi Team, any update?

Comment: Even i tried on running different port 5003 still same issue.

Comment: Hi Team, Any other checks need to do? Timely suggestion will be helpful for development in desktop version.